# How can I stop a docker container running sleep?

Tags: docker

`sleep` is a stand-in for most complex processes of course.

This Dockerfile (as you can see using the exec form so that there is only one process running and no children of `bash`):

```
FROM busybox
CMD ["/bin/sleep", "100000"]
```

creates an uninterruptible container:

```
docker build -t kill-sleep .
docker run --rm --name kill-sleep kill-sleep
```

When I try to stop it:

```
time docker stop kill-sleep

kill-sleep
real    0m10.449s
user    0m0.021s
sys     0m0.027s
```

the command times out at 10 seconds before the container is killed.

The problem isn't that `sleep` doesn't handle signals, because if I run it on the host:

```
sleep 100000
# in another shell
ps faxww | grep sleep
kill -TERM 31333  # the PID
```

the process stops immediately.

The problem may have to do with the fact that this is running as PID 1 in the container, but I have yet to see a reference documentation for that.

Answer (score 12):

When you run `docker stop ...`, [some things will happen](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/):

1. `docker` sends a `SIGTERM` to the main process of the container.
   The process is able to mask/ignore a `SIGTERM`, and if it does so (or handles it without terminating) "*nothing*" will happen.
2. After a timeout (default 10 seconds), `docker` sends a `SIGKILL` to the main process. This signal cannot be masked by a process, and thus it dies immediately with no opportunity for executing a shutdown prodedure.

Ideally, processes run within `docker` will respond to the `SIGTERM` in a timely fashion, taking care of any housekeeping before terminating.

If you know that the process either doesn't have any housekeeping to perform (e.g: `sleep`), or will not respond properly to `SIGTERM`, you can specify a shorter (or longer) timeout with the `-t` flag:

> ```
> -t, --time=10
>     Seconds to wait for stop before killing it
> ```

For example, in your case, you may like to run `docker stop -t 0 ${CONTAINER}`.

---

The reason that this signal behaviour is different is due to the `sleep` running with PID = 1.

Typically (e.g: running with PID != 1), any signal that the process doesn't explicitly deal with leads to the process being terminated - try sending a `sleep` a `SIGUSR1`.

However, when running with PID = 1, unhandled signals are ignored, otherwise you'd end up with a kernel panic:

```
Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!
```

---

You can send a signal to the docker container using docker tools, for example:

```
docker kill -s TERM kill-sleep
```

As we can see, this doesn't have the desired effect, whereas this does:

```
docker kill -s KILL kill-sleep
```

---

## An Experiment

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM busybox
COPY run.sh /run.sh
RUN chmod +x /run.sh
CMD "/run.sh"
```

#### run.sh

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

echo "sleeping"
sleep 100000
```

Now, run

```bsh
docker build -t kill-sleep .
docker run --rm --name kill-sleep kill-sleep
```

And this in a different terminal:

```bsh
docker stop kill-sleep
```

We observe the same 10 second delay / timeout.

## A Solution

Now let's handle the `SIGTERM`. Backgrounding and `wait`ing for `sleep` are due to how a POSIX shell handles signals (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26865972/1347519) for more).

#### run.sh

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

die_func() {
        echo "oh no"
        sleep 2
        exit 1
}
trap die_func TERM

echo "sleeping"
sleep 100000 &
wait
```

Run the commands again, and we see what we are after!

```
$ time docker stop kill-sleep
kill-sleep

real    0m2.515s
user    0m0.008s
sys     0m0.044s
```

Answer (score 1):

Some more options:

- add the `--init` switch to the container run command. This way, sleep is not PID 1, and init does the right thing on TERM.
- add the `--stop-signal=KILL` to the container run command. Using KILL as a somewhat normal operation is generally discouraged however.